# Bad fetch request (400) with Shopify, removing item from cart using /cart/change.js

Tags: javascript, fetch, shopify, cart

UPDATED WITH WORKING LINK

I am new to javascript as well as using a site like stackoverflow. If I am missing any info or can make it easier to help in someway just let me know. Really banging my head on this one.

I made a custom Shopify them for my store, and am attempting to make a custom cart drawer using ajax to add and remove products. The drawer itself, and adding products works, but I can't figure out removing products from the cart with ajax. Everything I do gets a Bad Request 400 error. Keep in mind the attempt in my code might be way off, or missing something very simple - either way I cannot figure it out and would appreciate any guidance.

here is the link: https://nwdc3mgqou964ccw-72877768986.shopifypreview.com

if you click a product on the front page, and add it to cart, the cart drawer will pop out and add the product.

JS and HTML are below.

```
// Open / Close Cart Bullshit
const openBtn = document.getElementById('open_cart_btn')
const cart = document.getElementById('sidecart')
const closeBtn = document.getElementById('close_btn')
const backdrop = document.querySelector('.backdrop')

openBtn.addEventListener('click', openCart)
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeCart)
backdrop.addEventListener('click', closeCart)

// Open Cart
function openCart(){
    cart.classList.add('open')
    backdrop.classList.add('show')
}

// Close Cart
function closeCart(){
  cart.classList.remove('open')
  backdrop.classList.remove('show')
}

// Event delegation for the close button
document.querySelector('.cart_content').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  const closeBtn = event.target.closest('.close_btn');
  if (closeBtn) {
      closeCart();
  }
});

async function updateCartDrawer() {

      const res = await fetch("/?section_id=cart-drawer");
    
      const text = await res.text();
      const html = document.createElement('div');
      html.innerHTML = text;

      const newCartContent = html.querySelector(".cart_content");
      const cartContent = document.querySelector(".cart_content");

      if (cartContent && newCartContent) {
          cartContent.innerHTML = newCartContent.innerHTML;
      }
}

const addToCartForms = document.querySelectorAll('form[action="/cart/add"]');

  addToCartForms.forEach((form) => {
  form.addEventListener("submit", async (event) => {
    //Prevent Normal Submission
    event.preventDefault();

    //Submit form with AJax
    await fetch("/cart/add", {
    method: "post", 
    body: new FormData(form), 
    });

    // Update cart
    await updateCartDrawer();

    // Open cart drawer when add to cart
    cart.classList.add('open')
    backdrop.classList.add('show')
   
    // Get new cart object
    const res = await fetch("/cart.json");
    const updatedCart = await res.json();
    
    // Update cart count
    document.querySelectorAll(".cart-count").forEach((el) => {
    el.textContent = updatedCart.item_count;
    });
  });
});


// Remove Item

document.querySelector('.cart_content').addEventListener('click', async function (event) {
  const removeItemBtn = event.target.closest('.remove_item');
  if (removeItemBtn) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const productId = removeItemBtn.getAttribute('data-product-id');
    
    // Make an AJAX request to remove the item from the cart

    const response = await fetch("/cart/change.js", {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify({ productId }), // Send the product ID or relevant data
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      // Item removed successfully, update the cart
      await updateCartDrawer();
    }
  }
});
```

```
<!-- Backdrop --> 
<div class="backdrop"></div>
<!-- Side Cart -->
<div id="sidecart" class="sidecart">
   <div class="cart_content" id="cart_content">
      <div class="cart_header">
         <a href="/cart" class="header__icon-wrapper tap-area tdf_cart_icon" aria-label="Cart" data-no-instant="">
            <svg focusable="false" width="20" height="18" class="icon icon--header-cart" viewBox="0 0 20 18">
               <path d="M3 1h14l1 16H2L3 1z" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2"></path>
               <path d="M7 4v0a3 3 0 003 3v0a3 3 0 003-3v0" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2"></path>
            </svg>
         </a>
         <div class="header_title">
            <h2> Cart </h2>
             <span style="margin-top:-55px;" id="items_sum" class="cart-link__bubble{% if cart.item_count > -1 %} cart-link__bubble--visible{% endif %}">{{ cart.item_count }}</span>
         </div>
         <span id="close_btn" class="close_btn"> &times; </span>
      </div>

         <div class="cart-counter" id="sidecart-counter"> 
        $0 <progress class="colored" max="7500" value="{{ cart.total_price }}"></progress> $75
       <br> {% if cart.items.size == 0 %}Add items to your cart to receive free shipping.{% endif %}{% if cart.items.size != 0 %}{% if cart.total_price >= 7500 %} You've got free shipping!{% elsif cart.total_price < 7500 %}You're only {{ 7500 | minus: cart.total_price | money }} away from free shipping.{% endif %}{% endif %}
    </div>

      {% if cart.item_count == 0 %}
      <p class="cart-empty"> Your cart is empty </p>
      {% else %}

      <!-- Cart Items -->
      <div class="cart_items">
         {% form 'cart', cart %}
         {% for item in cart.items %}
         <div class="cart_item">
          <a href="{{ item.url_to_remove }}">  
           <button class="remove_item" data-product-id="{{ item.id }}">
             <span>  &times;</span> 
            </button>
</a> 
        
            <div class="item_img"> 
               <img src="{{ item.image | img_url: '200x' }}" alt="{{ item.title }}">
            </div>
            <div class="item_details">
               <h3> {{ item.title }} 
            
            
               </h3>
              
              
               <p> 
               {{ item.final_line_price | money }} 
               </p>
                
             
           {% comment %}
               <div class="qty">
                  <span>-</span>
                  <strong>1</strong>
                  <span>+</span>
               </div>
            {% endcomment %}
          

            </div>
         </div>
         {% endfor %}
        

         {% endform %}
         {% endif %}
      </div>

  
      <!-- Cart Actions -->
      <div class="cart_actions">
 
        <div class="subtotal">
            <p>SUBTOTAL:</p>
            <p> {{ cart.total_price | money }} </p>
        </div>

               <div class="discounts">
            <p> Discounts applied at checkout</p>
            {% comment %} <p>{{ cart.total_discounts | money }} </p> {% endcomment %}
        </div>
      </div>
    <div id="cart-buttons">

            <a href="https://runforcoverrecords.com/pages/store"> <button> Keep Shopping </button> </a>
                
                <a href="https://runforcoverrecords.com/checkout">
            
            <div class="lock">

                <svg style="margin-top:-3px;" focusable="false" width="17" height="17" class="icon icon--lock" viewBox="0 0 17 17">
        <path d="M2.5 7V15H14.5V7H2.5Z" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" fill="none"></path>
        <path d="M5.5 4C5.5 2.34315 6.84315 1 8.5 1V1C10.1569 1 11.5 2.34315 11.5 4V7H5.5V4Z" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none"></path>
        <circle cx="8.5" cy="11" r="0.5" stroke="currentColor"></circle>
                </svg>
            </div>
            Checkout 
        </a>
        </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using both fetch and axios to remove products from the cart using the /cart/change.js shopify endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

To remove an item from the cart, you should use the variant ID and set the quantity to 0.
@eddieveddarfan69

```
  fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart/update.js', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    updates: {
      47172325736730: 0
    }
  }),
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```